# Rearrange coredata tableview cells (swift)

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I would like to be able to rearrange tableview cells, but I'm not sure how to get the new arrangement to save after it has be arranged. I am using NSFetchedResultsController  for my tableview and have uncommented this:

```
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

but I'm not sure how to implement what I need so that the order stays arranged how I want it after I navigate away from my tableview.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Check out answer to a similar question in the link below. None of the responses were considered complete. Note my method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413081/save-new-order-to-core-data-after-the-using-the-tableviewmoverowatindexpathtoi/28414122#28414122

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious and imho straight-forward way is to add an attribute for sorting to your managed object subclass. In `moveRowAtIndexPath` you can then reassign the sorting numbers.

The necessity of a new attribute seems logical, because a user defined order cannot be replicated consistently with any existing attributes. I have used this approach in countless apps.

In most situations it is feasible to quickly loop through all objects that need to "shift" their sorting number (usually up or down by one). In case of a large number of objects you could use an interval greater than 1, but such large numbers are rather rare in scenarios with user-defined ordering.